# Sanitize version for docker image versioning. nebula.release

Tags: java, docker, gradle, jib

I have a pipeline to build a Docker image in every push to specific branches in my git repository. The problem is that semantic versioning is using '+' character to specifying the metadata section in the version name. I need to replace this char for another supported by Docker in the image name. There is any way to replace that character or use a custom version name?

I am using nebula.release to inferring the project version.

```
id 'nebula.release' version '10.1.1'

jib {
    to {
        image = "registry.gitlab.com.uy:5005/project/app:$version"
        auth {
            username = System.getenv('CI_REGISTRY_USER')
            password = System.getenv('CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD')
        }
        tags = ['latest']
    }
    container {
        ports = ['8080']
        environment = [
                SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED: 'ALWAYS',
        ]
        useCurrentTimestamp = true
    }
    allowInsecureRegistries = true
}

jibDockerBuild.dependsOn bootJar
```

This is the error:

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':jib'.
>
>   > com.google.cloud.tools.jib.image.InvalidImageReferenceException: Invalid image reference:
>   >     registry.gitlab.com.uy:5005/project/app:1.0.0-rc.1.dev.0+108db18

I created this task in my build.gradle file, Is there any way to reuse it?

```
task cleanVersion {

    ext.sanitizeVersion = { version ->
        return version.toString().replace('+', '_')
    }
    doLast {
        println sanitizeVersion("$version")
    }
}
```

I could use some help. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Is `jib` a task here? You could do the replacement right in your string interpolation - `"registry.gitlab.com.uy:5005/project/app:${version.toString().replace('+', '_')}"`

Comment: @mkobit It's working! I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since build scripts are code and it looks like `jib` is an extension, `project.version` is a retrieval property (compared to a task output or something generated), you can use the same code you have in your current `cleanVersion` task to configure the extension.

```
image = "registry.gitlab.com.uy:5005/project/app:${version.toString().replace('+', '_')}"
```